# set new image when click a cell of gridview in android

Tags: android, gridview

**hey , how i can change the image of the cell i clicked in the grid view , what i should add to this code to show new image for example image"boxb" in the place of the image inserted before in the prgmImages list:**

**my custom adapter for the gridview "CAdapter" :**

```
public class CAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    int [] imageId;
    Context context;

    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public CAdapter(Context context, int[] prgmImages) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context=context;
        //context=level1;
        imageId=prgmImages;
        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return imageId.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        //TextView tv;
        ImageView img;
    }
    View rowView;

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Holder holder=new Holder();
        //View rowView;

        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.game_content, null);
        // holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        // holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
        holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

        rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  Toast.makeText(context, "what's up dude ! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent yourIntent = new Intent(context,QuestionA.class);
                yourIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
                v.getContext().startActivity(yourIntent);
            }
        });


        return rowView;
    }

}
```

**the Activity who use the gridview "Level1":**

```
public class Level1 extends Activity {
    GridView gv;
    Button hammer_btn;
    Button torch_btn;
    Context context;
    public static int[] prgmImages = {R.drawable.boxa, R.drawable.boxa, R.drawable.boxa, R.drawable.boxa, R.drawable.boxa, R.drawable.boxa};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.level1_window);
        gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        hammer_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        torch_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        context = this;
        gv.setAdapter(new CAdapter(this, prgmImages));

        gv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {

                if(position==0){
                    Intent iinent= new Intent(Level1.this,QuestionA.class);
                    startActivity(iinent);
                }


            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set  [OnItemClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) on your gridview. Method has parameter view and you just do this:

`public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageviewid);
imageView.setImageDrawable(yourdrawable);
}`

imageviewid is id of imageview inside your gridadapter, drawable is image you want to set which you can fetch with

```
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nameofdrawable);
```

**Explanation:**

Click listener has parameter 'View view' which returns layout of currently clicked item in gridview(R.layout.game_content in your case) and with findViewById you search for view by id ( id of imageview) and set it in new imageview then you just usestamdard methods for setting image.

Ask for any further help

Comment: thanks for the reponse , do u mean by imageviewid the id of the old image , if yes then how  i can get imageviewid because i insert them directly using a list  ?

Comment: Imageview id is imageview1 ( id of image view in your holder) and drawablename is name of image in res/drawable directory

Comment: thx ,now i undersand it , but i change this part (getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.boxb);) by this one(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.boxb, null);) because getDrawable in the first code the compiler make a line and say that it's deprecated , nothing happens when i run the app , old images don't change ??

Comment: Have you tested your solution is it actually getting drawable. Btw, my method even it says its deprecated its safe to use

Comment: yes i tested it too , but the new image dose not appear , however thank you for trying

Comment: Have you tried if click listener is being called when you click. Debug or put toast in it

Comment: yes because it take me to another activity , when i back to Level1 activity i find old images in thier place

Comment: Try without intent to see if it is changing. Im sure there is some silly mistake. Can you update your code in question

Comment: ah sorry i add the code that you say to  gv.setOnItemClickListener() of Level1 Activity , i tried to add it to the setOnItemClickListener() of CAdapter but compiler say "cannot resolve method getResources() " thx

Comment: If you want to use it in adapter you have to set getApplicationContext().getResources... If your adapter is inner class

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts I finally found the solution thx     :  ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                imageView.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.boxb));

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)